# Data from json file is not loading in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, json

Why my data is not loading in the table. I think i'm doing something wrong in  tag. It contains myModule but I'm setting myApp in the script. Please look at my code, tried everything but no help.

this is my index.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myModule">
    <head>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);

        myApp.controller('myController',function($scope,$http){
            $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
                $scope.countries = data;
        });

    });

    </script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="myController">

    <table border=1 cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td>Country</td><td>Capital</td></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="country in countries"><td>{{ country.name }}</td><td>{{ country.capital }}</td></tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my data.json file located in the same folder where my index.php is.

```
[

    {name: "India", capital: "New Delhi"},
    {name: "USA", capital: "Washington D.C."},
    {name: "Russia", capital: "Moscow"},
    {name: "France", capital: "Paris"},
    {name: "China", capital: "Beijing"},
    {name: "UK", capital: "London"}

]
```

Still no data appears in the table, please help.

Comment: Within a JSON-string keys and values are quoted. If you go to dev tools can you see the "get('data.json')" call? If yes, try to use double quotes on the json property names, as {"name": "India", "capital": "New Delhi"};

Comment: Try with `$scope.countries = data.data;`

Comment: Are you seeing in errors within your browser's console? Is the controller being initialized? Is angular attempting a GET call and is it successful according to your browser's dev tools?

Comment: @manzapanza, this would be true if he was using the traditional `then` promise return rather than the deprecated `success` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the response object to your countries. You should assign the response.data. Have a look at the [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

```
myApp.controller('myController',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(response){
        //$scope.countries = response;
        $scope.countries = result.data;
});
```

This is one thing I can see that is wrong with your code. But if your API is not working as it should, I would need error messages to help you further.